# Migrating executables that require I/O API to azure

Tags: azure

I have a number of executables that I want to migrate to azure. These executables require the I/O API in order to function properly. So in order to be able to migrate these executables I have to place them inside a cloud drive (VHD). But as far as I know a vhd can be mounted by one role at a time so how can I manage for let’s say 2 or more roles to mount the same VHD?

1. My first thought is to upload copies of the original VHD so each role can mount its own vhd and read/write to it and then save the files that all roles need to see in blob storage.
2. Make the VHD sharable via Using SMB to Share a Windows Azure Drive.

Which of the two solutions is better and is there another way I can deal with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Here's [a link](https://github.com/achilles-software/cloudstorageprovider) to an open source project that bridges System.IO calls to an ASP.NET cloud storage provider.